# String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM

Tags: security, mongodb, grails, spring-security, grails-orm

I'm trying to persist spring-security-acl domain objects in mongodb using grails mongo plugin. While executing following line of code

```
aclUtilService.addPermission Phone.class, phoneInstance.id, new PrincipalSid(username), BasePermission.ADMINISTRATION
```

I'm getting following error:

```
String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this  implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.. Stacktrace follows:
Message: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.
```

Any toughts?

**Grails Configuration Details:**

```
app.grails.version=2.0.3
app.name=eateri
app.servlet.version=2.5
app.version=0.1
plugins.mongodb=1.0.0.RC5
plugins.spring-security-acl=1.1
plugins.spring-security-core=1.2.7.2
```

Comment: GORM for mongo db does't support HQL queries - aclUtilService.addPermission probably uses hql which causes this error

Comment: are you experiencing this while running unit tests? It has no support for queries in unit:

Comment: @ACM64 - Not during unit test. It's during run-app

Comment: I got the same exception with GORM on MySQL, I think Grails doesn't support String queries in general on tests.

Answer (score 0):

As @sudhir mentioned, there are some methods in aclService using hql executeQuery method, like:

```
    protected AclObjectIdentity retrieveObjectIdentity(ObjectIdentity oid) {
        return AclObjectIdentity.executeQuery(
                "FROM AclObjectIdentity " +
                "WHERE aclClass.className = :className " +
                "  AND objectId = :objectId",
                [className: oid.type,
                 objectId: oid.identifier])[0]
        }
```

But mongodb gorm plugin does not support hql, therefore the calling path with which your code fall into hql error is like:

> aclUtilService.addPermission -> aclService.createAcl ->
>   retrieveObjectIdentity

And two other aclService methods using hql :

> deleteEntries, findChildren

So, a simple solution to this is to store ACL objects in mysql and [enable hibernate working with mongodb gorm](http://springsource.github.com/grails-data-mapping/mongo/manual/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.2%20Combining%20Mongo%20and%20Hibernate).

Anther one is to override these 3 aclService methods with [meta programming](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Dynamic+Groovy).